# Wordpress Gravity Forms Serialized List

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I've got a List field with Gravity Forms to populate some custom fields in a custom post type. The site is a recipe submission site, and I'm looking for users to be able to add ingredients individually for better SEO. My issue is, when I submit the form only the last input field under ingredients is passed to the recipe.

I know I need a serialized list as this custom field pulls an array, but I'm at a complete loss of how to do that. The array should read something like this

```
 a:8:{i:0;s:26:"4oz piece of salmon/person";i:1;s:12:"1 egg/person";i:2;s:37:"1-2 multi-colored bell peppers/person";i:3;s:12:"Greek olives";i:4;s:9:"Olive oil";i:5;s:13:"Salt & Pepper";i:6;s:22:"Basil (fresh or dried)";i:7;s:0:"";}
```

I don't even know where to begin in putting together a serialized array for one form field, so any nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Gravity Forms is configured to store these as separate meta records. One option is to customize the Gravity Forms `forms_model.php` file, `create_post` function, which unserializes the field contents and loops through each item to create a new `post_meta` record.

The following code should replace the case for field type `list`, and will prevent the creation of individual meta records on a predefined array of Gravity Form fields:

```
case "list" :
    $skipped_list_fields = array('<meta name for field to skip unserializing>',
        '<meta name for another field to skip unserializing>');
    $value = maybe_unserialize($value);
    if (in_array($meta_name, $skipped_list_fields)) {
        if(!rgblank($value))
            add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_name, $value);
    } else {
        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $item){
                if(is_array($item))
                    $item = implode("|", $item);

                if(!rgblank($item))
                    add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_name, $item);
            }
        }
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jason, someone had a similar situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591802/how-to-save-comma-separated-inputs-in-gravity-forms-to-a-global-array-on-form-su - I think a similar edit in functions.php in your theme is the direction...

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'm going for - although I'm trying to do it within a post. Looks like maybe I can use gform_save_field_value to create the array without affecting the initial data submission. I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

With a Custom Field form field configured as a List type and having filled out the form [like this](http://grab.by/sWn0), I'm seeing all the ingredients as separate post meta items (but all attached to the same key) [like this](http://grab.by/sWn2).

Is this different from what you are seeing or are you trying to achieve something different?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the way it is working currently. The issue is I need the data to be an array to make it work within my metafield (rather than trying to create multiple fields). So, one field with multiple values - that's why I'm looking to make it an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'List' field type from the 'Advanced Fields' area when creating/editing your form. That data is already serialized and saved as an array in a single field. Just use the gform_after_submission hook to save the GF field as postmeta.